# Update model of a grid store on the fly

Tags: extjs, model, grid, store, extjs5

A grid is configured with a store that use a model that I can call modelA

I need to change on the fly the model of the store related to the grid.
I followed following approach without results:

```
grid.getStore().setModel(modelB);

grid.reconfigure(
    grid.getStore(),
    columns
);

grid.getStore().load();
```

It continues to use the model defined at the beginning. In fact if I debug the record that is passed to the renderer function as follows:

```
function(value, metadata, record)...
```

record continues to reference modelA instead of modelB.

How can I change dynamically the model of the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that although you set new model you haven't re-read the records, at least you do not show any store.load() call. Models are used by store/proxy/reader to create instances when the store is loaded.

Now, I wouldn't use this approach anyway. Store is not a very expensive in terms of performance or memory so if I'd need to reconfigure the grid I'd use another store with that another model.

Comment: Creating a new store I can add it a new model created on the fly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this task, you can change fields of model dynamically instead of changing the model itself. Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lwkmy5d/)

```
  store.model.setFields(fieldsArray);
  store.load();  // or store.load(newData);
  grid.reconfigure(store,columnInfo);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using the version 5.0.1... It doesn't seem I have a "setFields" method for the model.